# R Recursive Function and map() for Bill Data Structure

Tags: r, function, recursion, byte-order-mark, recursive-datastructures

Using R tibbles, I have a df as shown below. It's a BOM data structure.

```
    df <- data.frame(
    product_id= c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2"),
    item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", "i17", "i18"),
    sup_item_id= c("i6","i6","i6","i6","i8", "i8", "i9", "i9",NA, "i15","i15","i15","i15","i17", "i17", "i18", "i18",NA),
    quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4,1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4,1, 1),
    price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0),
    itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A","B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A","B", "C"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

I am applying a function df_path to identify all df paths based on the recursive relationship between item_ids and sup_item_ids (parent/child).

```
    dfpath_f <- function(item,pr){
    parent <- subset(df, 
                     item_id==item & product_id==pr)$sup_item_id
    if(is.na(parent)) return(item)
    c(item,Recall(parent,pr))
}
```

Now when I call it I use map() function to avoid for loop

```
df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(dfpath = map2(item_id, product_id, dfpath_f),
           level = lengths(dfpath)-1,
           product = map(dfpath, last))
```

the output is something like this:

```html
 product_id item_id sup_item_id quantity price itemtype             dfpath level product
        P1      i1          i6        2     2        A     i1, i6, i8, i9     3      i9
        P1      i2          i6        2     5        A     i2, i6, i8, i9     3      i9
        P1      i3          i6        5     3        A     i3, i6, i8, i9     3      i9
        P1      i4          i6        1     7        A     i4, i6, i8, i9     3      i9
        P1      i5          i8        1    10        A         i5, i8, i9     2      i9
        P1      i6          i8        2     0        B         i6, i8, i9     2      i9
        P1      i7          i9        4     4        A             i7, i9     1      i9
        P1      i8          i9        1     0        B             i8, i9     1      i9
        P1      i9        <NA>        1     0        C                 i9     0      i9
        P2     i10         i15        2     2        A i10, i15, i17, i18     3     i18
        P2     i11         i15        2     5        A i11, i15, i17, i18     3     i18
        P2     i12         i15        5     3        A i12, i15, i17, i18     3     i18
        P2     i13         i15        1     7        A i13, i15, i17, i18     3     i18
        P2     i14         i17        1    20        A      i14, i17, i18     2     i18
        P2     i15         i17        2     0        B      i15, i17, i18     2     i18
        P2     i16         i18        4     2        A           i16, i18     1     i18
        P2     i17         i18        1     0        B           i17, i18     1     i18
        P2     i18        <NA>        1     0        C                i18     0     i18
```

Now what I want to do exactly is to create a new column for total price to calculate the total costs for each dfpath based on the fact that each node in my df structure has children and the value of nodes must be calculated based on the sum of price*quantity of its children recursively from the bottom to the top(product).
How can I adjust my dfpath to get these values or create a new recursive function that does this?

Comment: Have you considered using `data.tree`? The [tree traversal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#tree-traversal) section of the documentation explains how to walk trees in various orders.

Comment: I wanted to use only R tidyverse library and solve it without data.tree